# how to connect eWeLink to google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-smart-home

I want to connect between a smart power switch app(eWelink for example) to google app scripts.
The problem is the API(https://ewelink-api.vercel.app/docs/introduction) uses a library which isn't possible to use in google app scripts. What is the easiest way to bypass this?

Comment: You can install node module with Apps Script with the help of Clasp.. but it require some setup

Answer (score 0):

I recommend sending the data collected by the eWeLink API to Google Spreadsheets, then interacting with it through Google App Scripts . You can get more information in this regard [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#node.js).